# In Microsoft bot framework, How to include a star rating feedback

Tags: botframework, bots

I am using microsoft bot framework. I need to implement a star rated feedback mechanism in my code. Like selecting the star should submit the rating for the bot. Can anyone help me on this? or any suggestions ?

Answer (score 5):

You can create a star rating feedback card with an AdaptiveCard by making columns behave like submit buttons. To begin, add a column set to an AdaptiveCard with the desired number of columns - each column will correspond to a rating. Then in each column, you can add an image of a star or some other object and a text field describing that rating. Next, add a submit action to each column and in the data field add the value of the response. Finally, you can render the card and send it to the user as an attachment. When the user clicks on a column, it will send the value from the data field as a message from the user.  See the AdaptiveCard JSON and screenshot of the rendered card below for an example.

#### Screenshot

[image]

#### JSON AdaptiveCard

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "size": "Medium",
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "color": "Accent",
            "text": "Rate your experience!"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "separator": true,
            "text": "Please rate your experience! Your feedback is very appreciated and will help improve your experience in the future. ",
            "wrap": true
        },
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "spacing": "Medium",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "selectAction": {
                        "type": "Action.Submit",
                        "data": "awful"
                    },
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Image",
                            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                            "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Five-pointed_star.svg"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                            "text": "Awful"
                        }
                    ],
                    "width": "stretch"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "selectAction": {
                        "type": "Action.Submit",
                        "data": "bad"
                    },
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Image",
                            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                            "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Five-pointed_star.svg"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                            "text": "Bad"
                        }
                    ],
                    "width": "stretch"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "selectAction": {
                        "type": "Action.Submit",
                        "data": "ok"
                    },
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Image",
                            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                            "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Five-pointed_star.svg"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                            "text": "Ok"
                        }
                    ],
                    "width": "stretch"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "selectAction": {
                        "type": "Action.Submit",
                        "data": "good"
                    },
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Image",
                            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                            "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Five-pointed_star.svg"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                            "text": "Good"
                        }
                    ],
                    "width": "stretch"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "selectAction": {
                        "type": "Action.Submit",
                        "data": "terrific"
                    },
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Image",
                            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                            "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Five-pointed_star.svg"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                            "text": "Terrific"
                        }
                    ],
                    "width": "stretch"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

Comment: How about C# display the star rating

Comment: If you open a new question, I’ll take a look at it. It’s too much code for the comment section.

Comment: @tdurnford I had open the Question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55312256/duplicate-rating-in-prompt-choice

Comment: SVGs aren't supported by MS Teams for anyone using that channel, transparent background PNGs are better for Teams.