# Duplicate Rating in Prompt.Choice

Tags: c#, botframework

I had Question in Bot Framework SDK V3.
When the answer is selected, then the bot reply and the bot ask to rate again.
Here with the screenshot.
[image]
and Here with my code:

```
private const string fiverate = "★★★★★";
private const string fourrate = "★★★★";
private const string threerate = "★★★";
private const string tworate = "★★";
private const string Onerate = "★";

public async Task ShowRating(IDialogContext context)
{
    PromptDialog.Choice(context,this.OnOptionRating, new List<string>() { fiverate,fourrate,threerate,tworate,Onerate }," "," ",3);          
}

private async Task OnOptionRating(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
{
    try
    {
        string optionSelected = await result;

        switch (optionSelected)
        {
            case fiverate:
                await context.PostAsync("Five Star");
                context.Done(String.Empty);
                break;
            case fourrate:
                await context.PostAsync("Four Star");
                context.Done(String.Empty);
                break;
            case threerate:
                await context.PostAsync("Three Star");
                context.Done(String.Empty);
                break;
            case tworate:
                await context.PostAsync("Two Star");
                context.Done(String.Empty);
                break;
            case Onerate:
                await context.PostAsync("One Star");
                context.Done(String.Empty);
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (TooManyAttemptsException ex)
    {
        await context.PostAsync($"Ooops! Too many attemps :(. But don't worry, I'm handling that exception and you can try again!");

        context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
}
```

any solutions better for this? I had reference so many sample from Stack Overflow, but still not found the solutions.

Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.  Are you asking for a more efficient algorithm for a bot to re-ask one to vote? or are you asking how to have the bot not ask to re-vote?

Comment: @N8888 i want to ask any solution to avoid the bot reply the answer and ask to do rating again.

Comment: I dont see why you would like to run an infinite loop of asking the user a rating

Comment: @gdvigneshwar this is the issue I want to solve, any solutions for this? Because I want to stop the loop of rating.

Comment: Ok I suggest you take a look at waterfall dialogs in botframework. It will help you out with your problem

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: @gdvigneshwar I had use the adaptive card. but the end it still a issue.

Comment: You haven't shown us any of your relevant code. Where is your entry point? Where is `ShowRating` getting called from?

Answer (score 0):

I had change to the waterfall model. Its solved my problems. Thank you.